# Print only specific values from json data from a API

Tags: python, api

I want to get only specific values from the api and print it. It should also be printed in JSON because I have to again post it to some other api.

```
import requests
auth =('demo', 'demo')
r = requests.get('https://api.demo.com/v1/demo?count=100', auth=auth)
dataa = r.json()
data = dataa['items']['id','amount','newid','email']
print(data)
```

my code gives error. when i put `dataa["items"][0]['id']` It only gets me one value
 Response:

```
{
    "entity": "collection",
    "count": 5,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "U5GM",
            "entity": "pay",
            "amount": 3000,

            "bank": null,
            "vpa": null,
            "email": "shaza1@gmail.com",
            "contact": "1349714",
            "notes": {
                "newid": "554545"
            }

        }}
```

expected output:

```
 {
            "id": "U5GM",
            "amount": 3000,
            "email": "shaza1@gmail.com",
            "contact": "1349714",
             "newid": "554545"

        }
```

Comment: what is the Problem if you have that response ?

Comment: I don't want unnecessary values to be stored in my db

Comment: what datatype do you want to have

Comment: string would be fine, i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `items` is a `list`. Are you only interested in the `first` batch ?
If yes, then you could do,

```
>>> items = data['items']
>>> data_to_post = []
>>> for item in items:
...   data_to_post.append({
...     'id': item.get('id', 'NA'),
...     'email': item.get('email', 'NA'),
...     'amount': item.get('amount', 'NA'),
...     'newid': item.get('notes', {'newid': 'NA'})['newid']
...   })
... 
>>> data_to_post
[{'id': 'U5GM', 'email': 'shaza1@gmail.com', 'amount': 3000, 'newid': '554545'}]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198481/discussion-on-answer-by-han-solo-print-only-specific-values-from-json-data-from).

Answer (score 0):

Try to first store each value you are interested in in a dictionary and then convert that dictionary to json.

```
import json

date_to_store = []

for i in range(len(dataa["items"])):
    data = {}
    data['id'] = dataa["items"][i]['id']
    data['amount'] = dataa["items"][i]['amount']
    data['email'] = dataa["items"][i]['email']
    data['newid'] = dataa["items"][i]['notes']['newid']

    date_to_store.append(data)

json = json.dumps(data_to_store)
print(json )
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks but i need all the data. not only [0]

Comment: count can also be 100

Comment: I changed my answer to loop, it will loop *count* times and store everything in *data_to_store*

Comment: data['newid'] = dataa["items"][i]['notes']['newid']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Changed count to *len(dataa["items"])*

Comment: Check the error message I have added in the above comment

Comment: This answer is also correct but I am accepting the other one because of the efforts involved

Answer (score 0):

you can use this Code to extract the values you need from the Response and then add it to whatever datatype you like:

```
d= {}

for k, v in j["items"][0].items():
    if k in ["id", "amount", "newid", "email"]:
        d[k] = v

print(d)
```